# Mac Book Air 13" (2011) - Wifi continuosly disconnecting

Tags: macos, wifi, macbook-pro

Last October I bought my first Mac, a Macbook Air 13". It works perfectly except for the wifi: I can be connected for hours without problems, but then it suddenly disconnects. The wifi widget doesn't change, and the way I solve it is disconnecting and reconnecting again.

I can't find the way to trigger this behaviour, which can happen after some minutes, or hours.

This doesn't happen with the other PCs that connect to the same wifi, nor with the iPhone.

I use WPA encryption; a friend of mine suggested using WEP to solve it, but I want to have a more secure network.

What could I do?

UPDATE:

I don't know if this can be important for the issue. I bought the MBA in USA (NewYork) and I live in Spain, Europe, could it be possible to have some slightly different technology/software interfering?

I have it updated to the last version

The exact model of the router is Huawei HG532c

UPDATE2:

Links that may help, seems like a is Lion issue

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2664670?start=0&tstart=0
https://discussions.apple.com/message/16785261#16785261

Comment: Are the logs saying anything? To check them, use console.app

Comment: Which version of OS X are you running?

Comment: Juan, I'm not as familiar with the wifi spectrum in Europe but my experience could still help.  In my answer below, my wife's MBA was using channel 1 from our access point.  I changed it to 6 and the issue went away.  If that fails to resolve the issue, try channel 11 if available.  The idea is to switch it away to a less congested frequency.

Comment: I'm updated to the last Lion version macaco, bg2011 as soon as I arrive home I'll try your suggestion, thanks

Comment: changing channel to an unused one didn't help

Answer (score 1):

I've had this experience with my wife's MBA and discovered our wifi channel was to close to other access points in the neighborhood.  You would think this nearby interference would cause connection problems throughout the day but it actually occurred just like you've described.  Ok for hours than down hard.

I changed the channel on our access point away from the nearby channels and the problem went away completely.

You can use an app like iStumbler to view available networks and what channels they are using.  To view the wifi connection for your MBA, hold down the Option key and click on the wifi icon in the menu bar.

Comment: changing channel to an unused one didn't help, I have a neighbout wifi that is received better than mine

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with my MBP, it would stop itself connecting, and generate it's own IP (169..). I solved it by using static IPs. Perhaps this could help?